# Java Image Import Display

Tags: java

I am having trouble understanding if I am reading my images in correctly. My code with a random Bill Gates Picture:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ReadingImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        //readImage("billgates.jpg");


        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("billgates.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that a java icon pops up  on the doc(mac user) but no window or anything displays it.

Can you save images into arrays and display them on demand, ie is there a function for displaying? I don't recall the above code actually requesting the image to be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you are not displaying anything here, just loading the image from the file.

If you want to use Swing, you can display an image with an ImageIcon, for example in a JLabel. See [the tutorial from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).

Also, you really don't want to put nothing in your catch(IOException e) block. At least put some code to print out the error. It's almost always a very bad thing to silently ignore an exception:

```
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("billgates.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e); // print error
}
```

Comment: In my code, is the image successfully saved in the variable "img"? Also, I will be importing multiple images in, so is it feasible to store it all in array and then use your suggested method in Swing to display it?

Comment: If the image is not read correctly, then either `img` is null or an exception will throw. Test your code to see if it is. You can use a `BufferedImage[]` to store your images if you want.